# Staying up late

Tags: grammar

Can you say:

> ''Just as I expected, the more I stay up late, the harder for me to wake up early.''

Is this grammatical? If yes, could you help pls. this sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Just as I expected, the more I stay up late, the harder **it is** for me to wake up early.